# How to make a faceted waffle chart, filling each bin from top left

Tags: r, ggplot2, waffle-chart

I'm trying to create a 3x4 grid of bins with a count of observations from my data in each bin. I'm halfway there:

```
library(ggplot2)
type <- c('daily', 'daily', 'habit', 'habit', 'habit', 'seasonal', 'seasonal', 'year-long', 'year-long', 'year-long', 'year-long', 'year-long')
status <- c('complete', 'incomplete', 'push', 'push', 'incomplete', 'complete', 'complete', 'complete', 'complete', 'push', 'push', 'incomplete')
results <- data.frame(type, status)

ggplot(results) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(x=status, y=type), binwidth=.2) +
  facet_grid(vars(type))
```

[image: result]

Clearly the y-axis is meaningless right now - I'm not sure if `geom_dotplot` is the right thing to use. I can get similar results with `geom_histogram` or `geom_bar` as well.

**I'd like dots to start in the upper left corner of each bin.** Is this possible? I've tried to use the `waffle` [package](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle) but can't figure it out. Ideally each dot will be a square, which isn't possible using `geom_dotplot`, so I'd prefer to use `waffle` if I can.

Comment: What is the code you tried using `waffle` package? Also can you sketch desired result?

Comment: ```ggplot(results, aes(fill=type, values=sum(as.integer(status)) )) +
  geom_waffle() +
  facet_wrap(status~type) +
  coord_equal()```

Not sure what my result was doing here...also encountered the problem with the `waffle` package mentioned below ("invalid 'times' argument with `facet_grid`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently an open [issue](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle/issues/66) with that waffle package which prevented me from producing the chart the way I wanted to (getting an error "invalid 'times' argument"), using facet_grid along both status and type.

Alternatively, we can do some data prep to create something similar.

```
rows <- 4
cols <- 4

results %>%
  arrange(status, type) %>%
  group_by(status, type) %>%
  mutate(num = row_number(),
         x_pos = (num - 1) %/% rows,
         y_pos = rows - (num - 1) %% rows - 1) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x = x_pos, y = y_pos)) +
  geom_tile(fill = "black", color = "white") +
  coord_equal(xlim = c(0, cols) - 0.5,
              ylim = c(0, rows) - 0.5) +
  facet_grid(vars(type), vars(status)) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. I was thinking I needed to add something to the data to make it easier but could not figure it out.